# Chart X Axis and Textbox numbering

Tags: report, ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services

I've been searching but not found anything about it.
I have two questions.

How can I get a **numbered** label on the x axis in the chart?

Example:

1,2,3,4....

And how can I have a numbering using multiple textbox?

Edited:
I have a report that has several textbox's.
Example:

1.General
1.1-Type1
1.2-Type2
1.3-Type3

All titles are in different textbox and so the numbering always comes back to the first value.

For graphics I wanted to put a number or a sequence of letters.

Comment: You should really be more specific on what you've tried, add more details to your question, and in general review your question to see if it's understandable/answerable by other users (that don't have any context besides what you've provided).

Comment: The question was edited. I think it is more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can I get a numbered label on the x axis in the chart?

Example:

1,2,3,4....

Answer: 
Use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in Query to numbered filed then use that fiels to label on the x axis in the chart..

Comment: here is the sample code you can add in your SP. Or post your SP code!!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx